# Double-quoted include [all Facebook SDK imports], expected angle-bracketed instead

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-warnings

I am getting the following warning in iOS Xcode builds:

```
    Double-quoted include "FBSDKDeviceLoginCodeInfo.h" in framework header, expected angle-bracketed instead.
```

This is apparently a new default warning in Xcode 12 which will throw a warning anywhere you #import or #include with "quotes.h" instead of <brackets.h>.

I am getting this for all of the Facebook SDK imports. There are a few StackOverflow proposed solutions out there, but none of them works.

These solutions do not work:

1. go in the project's Build Settings a just set the option Quoted Include In Framework Header to No :
2. you can use Cocoapods version 1.10.0.rc.1 temporarily until 1.10.1 is officially available -> gem install cocoapods -v '1.10.0.rc.1'
3. Another option is to update your Podfile (add below code) to disable the warning flag CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER setting for all pods in your project

   ```
   post_install do |installer|
     installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
       project.targets.each do |target|
         target.build_configurations.each do |config|
             config.build_settings['CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER'] = 'NO'
         end
       end
     end
   end
   ```
4. You can disable these warnings for your entire project by navigating to your project's "build settings", finding the field "other linker flags" and adding the following flag: -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header
5. Worked for me:

   ```
   rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
   rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/
   pod deintegrate
   pod update
   ```

These solutions were written 7 or 8 months ago and **DO NOT WORK FOR ME**.
Are there any new solutions beyond manually editing hundreds of occurrences of this?

Comment: Try adding `inhibit_all_warnings!` to your `Podfile` .

Comment: @Yonat Is there a particular place to put this command in the Podfile? I put it at the end of the file and it had no impact. After inserting this command in the Podfile, I entered pod update.

Comment: I put  it near the top,  right after `use_frameworks!` .

Comment: @Yonat Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I am still getting this warning. It may have decreased the number of warnings, but they are still there for a few files: FBSDKAppEvents.h, FBSDKGraphErrorRecoveryProcessor.h, FBSDKProfile.h, and FBSDKLoginButton.h. Any other thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't know, sorry.